# Sorting Range Left to Right from Row 2

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have 3 rows in excel with numbers that I want to sort left to right from smallest to largest values of Row 2 in VBA.

**I found how to do it based on first row:**

```
Range(Rows(1),Rows(3)).Sort Key1:=Range(Rows(1),Rows(3)), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
```

**This is what I have:** 

 5,6,2,1

4,3,2,1

a,d,w,x

**This is what I want:** 

 1,2,6,5

 1,2,3,4

 x,w,d,a

any ideas what little line of code i need to add to what I have that will make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change** `Key1:=Range(Rows(1),Rows(3))` to `Key1:=Rows(2)`

**Try:**

```
Range(Rows(1), Rows(3)).Sort Key1:=Rows(2), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
```

**Demo:**

[image]